# I have build control panel with same code but now, i am getting a issue, though its same codse but not showing same result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have build control panel with same code but now, i am getting a issue, though its same codes but not showing same result.
I have provided my code and pictures below..
What is my mistake or what i am forgetting, review my code and tell me please
Plase help me..
Please see my code :

## ASPX Code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StudentDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="StudentDetails" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Staff Access | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/morris/morris.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="L1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="L3" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="adminTS.aspx" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>S.</b>A</span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Staff</b> Access</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
          <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogout" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" CausesValidation="false">
              Logout <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>

            </asp:LinkButton>

          </li>
          <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
         <!-- <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">-->
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" CssClass="img-circle" />
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">  
            <asp:Label ID="lblProfilePic" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
        </div>
      <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li class="active treeview">
          <a href="adminTS.aspx" id="Staff_Control">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>Staff Control
                                            </span>

          </a>
          <!--<ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a></li>
            <li><a href="index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>
          </ul>-->
        </li>
        <li id="li" class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <span>View HOD</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="pages/widgets.html">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Staff</span>

              <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>

            </span>
          </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>First Year</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Second Year</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Third Year</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
            <span>Student Details</span></a>

        </li>
          <li class="treeview">
              <a href="">
                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                  <span>Publish CT Result</span>
                  <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>First Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Second Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Third Year</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
                  <span>Attendance</span>
                  <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>First Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Second Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Third Year</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                  <span>Provide Notes</span>
                  <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                  <li><a href="Provide_Notes_FY.aspx"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>First Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Provide_Notes_SY.aspx"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Second Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Provide_Notes_TY.aspx"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Third Year</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="treeview">
              <a href="Staff_NT.aspx">
                  <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                  <span>Provide Notice</span>

              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                  <span>Contact Parents</span>
                  <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>First Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Second Year</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Third Year</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="treeview">
          <a href="Forum.aspx">
            <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
            <span>Forum Discussion</span>



          </a>

        </li>





    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <!--<h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Control panel</small>
      </h1>-->

    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

        <div class="center-block">
            <<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Student_Enrollment_No" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Enrollment_No" HeaderText="Student_Enrollment_No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Student_Enrollment_No" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Name" HeaderText="Student_Name" SortExpression="Student_Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Gender" HeaderText="Student_Gender" SortExpression="Student_Gender" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Phone" HeaderText="Student_Phone" SortExpression="Student_Phone" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Division" HeaderText="Student_Division" SortExpression="Student_Division" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Current_Semester" HeaderText="Student_Current_Semester" SortExpression="Student_Current_Semester" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SCDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Student_Enrollment_No], [Student_Name], [Student_Gender], [Student_Phone], [Student_Division], [Student_Current_Semester] FROM [Students_Table] WHERE (([Student_Division] = @Student_Division) AND ([Student_Current_Semester] = @Student_Current_Semester) AND ([Year] = @Year))">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="L1" Name="Student_Division" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="L2" Name="Student_Current_Semester" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="L3" Name="Year" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>


     </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version</b> 2.3.8
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2016 <a href="http://almsaeedstudio.com">Almsaeed Studio</a>.</strong> All rights
    reserved.
  </footer>

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Create the tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
      <li><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Home tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>

                <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-user bg-yellow"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Frodo Updated His Profile</h4>

                <p>New phone +1(800)555-1234</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-envelope-o bg-light-blue"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Nora Joined Mailing List</h4>

                <p>nora@example.com</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-file-code-o bg-green"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Cron Job 254 Executed</h4>

                <p>Execution time 5 seconds</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Custom Template Design
                <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Update Resume
                <span class="label label-success pull-right">95%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 95%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Laravel Integration
                <span class="label label-warning pull-right">50%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 50%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Back End Framework
                <span class="label label-primary pull-right">68%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" style="width: 68%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Stats tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Settings tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
          <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Report panel usage
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Some information about this general settings option
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Allow mail redirect
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Other sets of options are available
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Expose author name in posts
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Allow the user to show his name in blog posts
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Chat Settings</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Show me as online
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Turn off notifications
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right">
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Delete chat history
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-red pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#HOD_Panel").click(function () {

                $("#Add_HOD").load("AddHOD/ahod.aspx");
                });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#HOD_Panel").click(function () {
                $("#Remove_HOD").load("AddHOD/RemoveHOD.aspx");
            });
        });

    </script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Expected Result like this :

[image]

## Actual Result I am getting :

[image]

## C# Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class StudentDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["StaffUsername"] != null)
            {
                lblProfilePic.Text = Session["StaffUsername"].ToString();
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCDB"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Year,Semester,Department FROM Staff_Table WHERE Username=@Username", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",lblProfilePic.Text);
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if(sdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while(sdr.Read())
                        {
                            string year = (string)sdr["Year"];
                            string semester = (string)sdr["Semester"];
                            string department = (string)sdr["Department"];
                            L1.Text = year;
                            L2.Text = semester;
                            L3.Text = department;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Please help me..
Thank you

Comment: the markup you posted corresponds to the actual result (contains the text "Staff Access"). so the problem must be on server side, how do you render this page and what conditions need to be met to make it render the librarian access?

Comment: I check if its post back or not, then session check then rest of code depend upon session, if session is getting its required parameter, then page will be loaded, else it will be not

Comment: ok, then in this case please show the *code that leads to the wrong page* being served, instead of the page markup. or do you expect StudentDetails.aspx to render two different views?

Comment: You need the C# code ??

Comment: a minimal, complete example to reproduce the faulty behavior. and a better understanding of what's actually going wrong - the two pages are considerably different, where does the "expected result" really come from?

Comment: See, i added my C# code of faulty behavior page